# Tire uneven wear - cause and appropriate preventative action?

Tags: tires, maintenance, suspension, alignment, wear

The inside of the tires are worn as seen in the attached photos (both front and rear).  This is an SUV with about 80k miles on it.  Any ideas on 1) what would cause this, 2) how the car could develop that issue in the first place, and 3) what corrective step(s) should be taken?

From reading online it looks like something to do with camber, but why would that develop in the first place and what's the best solution?

Update: Make/Model/Year = 2011 Toyota Sequoia

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding the make, model and year may provide  more specific answers. Have you been rotating the tires regularly?

Comment: @mikes we haven't been rotating them regularly, but if the wear pattern is the same on the front and the rear tires, wouldn't that not be a complete solution?

Comment: If you had been rotating the problem may have been isolated to the front. Thee are a variety of suspension types. But again without the make model and year the community can't supply anymore than speculation.

Comment: @mikes +1 to adding make/model/year :)

Comment: @mikes Added make/modelyear - thx

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things that could be happening. You could have old shocks or springs which are allowing the car to sag a bit, some of your suspension components might be wearing, allowing play, or you could simply need an alignment done. Every time you drive your car a couple of tons of metal is resting on your suspension components, bumps and dips slamming everything around. Over time that's going to cause wear, and things are going to shift so parts will need to be replaced and the suspension adjusted so that the car rides evenly on the wheels. It's perfectly normal and not indicating any major problem, just routine maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Many factors can affect tire wear. Driving habits, tire pressure, suspension design, overall load, road surface, and on and on.

The point of camber being the cause would assume that it’s based on suspension design. That may be the case, but as noted in comments, it’s just speculation without knowing the make/model/year. A sportier SUV may have factory cambered suspension, while one that’s more off-road oriented may have softer, longer-travel, suspension which is sagging more by design.

I think the most important thing to look at is that all 4 tires seem to be pretty even - that’s a good thing. If this were because of mechanical damage, it would likely be only 1 wheel, and very rarely more.

It can also just be cause by turning. Usually you’ll see the outside of a tire wear faster than the inside, but it’s not a stretch to think that it could be reversed. As I say, a sportier SUV may be cambered. It would also likely have tighter suspension. That would definitely cause inner-tire wear.